# Magento: Bundle Products (LONG SERVER REQUEST)

Tags: database, magento, bundle

I have been working with magento, our store only uses bundle products, and as we have started to have a large amount of data (10,000 simple products) (around 1500 bundle products)

I Have noticed that saving and requesting has become a lot larger, when I have ran the Mysql request check I can see then when selecting 'bundle items' in the product screen it will request every single, single product within the database.

I was wondering if anyone has come across the same problem or issue?

Comment: Configure magento to use Flat table instead of every attribute table. go to System->Configuration->Catalog->Use Product Flat table: yes. Also enable cache.

Comment: Hi Rajiv, Thanks for replying, however both of these are on.

Regardless of flat products, the query still runs every single simple product entity id, What it is doing is collecting all the information prior to the next screen.

Comment: Only I can suggest, if you have dedicated server, then you can go for memcache or APC cache. I have also installed external cache module for most of my magento projects for speed-up.

Comment: I Raj, I also have memcache, gzip, mysql optimisation all running which is why our website is fast.

Im trying to find out where this bundle query is being launched so I can potentially manipulate or adjust it.